# What method is called before viewDidLoad() but after main?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I observed that `viewDidLoad()` is called before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()` and I am looking for something where I can put some initialization code that has to be called before `viewDidLoad()`.

Is there such a place?

Also, it is acceptable to recall viewDidLoad() from other place. It should be ok, or too risky?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are wrong.

Place a NSLog directly under the method header and you will see that ViewDidLoad is directly called after.

```
[self.window addSubview:self.yourViewController.view];
```

So, you either use viewDidLoad or alternatively and not really beautiful you could use.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

This even gets called before ViewDidload

Answer (score 3):

There's

```
 - loadView()
```

Kicks in before `viewDidLoad()` and comes with an advice to never be called directly after that. 
Here's the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView) to the apple docs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once that was caused when I added the view controller I wanted added to the window using the MainWindow.xib file.

To get around this, I assigned the window's rootViewController (you can also call addSubView, but assigning the rootViewController is better) in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of the app delegate.  Once you do this you can easily put whatever logic you want in front or behind where this happens.  It puts you in full control of when your view controller loads.  In contrast, when the view controller is loaded via the nib, it's difficult to execute code in front of it (if at all possible).  I know you sepecify the main xib in the app's plist, but I don't know if there is a way to run code before that nib is loaded.

In general I avoid adding the view controller in the xib for this reason.

My code looks more like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   // special pre load logic here...

   UIViewController *myVC = [[MyAwesomeViewController alloc] init];
   self.window.rootViewController = myVC;
   [myVC release];

   // special post load logic here...

   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do your app initializations in viewDidLoad, however don't do any boundaries or size settings here, as they are not yet set.

Do them in viewDidLayoutSubviews, which is called after viewDidLoad.

I found this article, which was very helpful to me:

[The UIViewController lifecycle](https://stevenpcurtis.medium.com/the-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle-b964cf18256b)

Answer (score -2):

You could put initialization code in the `init` method of the class.

And it's fine to call `viewDidLoad` again from elsewhere. It's just like any other method.

**EDIT:**

It's fine to call `viewDidLoad` - but you should be careful with memory management. If you're allocating objects in `viewDidLoad`, calling it again will cause leaks. So, because of the typical functionality of `viewDidLoad`, you might want to pull the code out into another method that you'll call repeatedly and call from `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: calling viewDidLoad manually should be avoided as it is part of the view lifecycle.  Normally, initialization of additional view elements should be done inside viewDidLoad.  Calling viewDidLoad manually will at worst leak memory and at best cause unnecessary allocs to be performed.  Instead, take whatever logic you want to trigger, place it in another method that is safe to call multiple times and call it from viewDidLoad.

Comment: I disagree. Memory management is a separate concern and your points about unnecessary allocations and leaks are valid. But if viewDidLoad does not allocate memory, calling it again is fine.

Comment: yes, technically.  But it's a bad habit to get into and should be avoided.